# draw Broken line graph using dynamic data display?

Tags: c#, wpf, dynamic-data-display

Can i draw Broken line graph using dynamic data display ?

In my application i need to draw a real time `voltage/time graph.My requirement` is, i should draw graph lines only if the voltage is not a `0` .

How can i achieve that?

I tried the following :

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public ObservableDataSource<Point> source1 = null;
        public ObservableDataSource<Point> source2 = null;
        public ObservableDataSource<Point> source3 = null;
        public ObservableDataSource<Point> source4 = null;
        public ObservableDataSource<Point> source5 = null;
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.Loaded += MainWindow_Loaded;
        }

        private void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {        
            source1 = new ObservableDataSource<Point>();
            source2 = new ObservableDataSource<Point>();
            source3 = new ObservableDataSource<Point>();
            source4 = new ObservableDataSource<Point>();
            source5 = new ObservableDataSource<Point>();
            source1.SetXYMapping(p => p);

            testchart.AddLineGraph(source1, 1, "Data row");
            testchart.AddLineGraph(source2, Color.FromRgb(7, 10, 67), 1, "Data row");
            testchart.AddLineGraph(source3, Color.FromRgb(6, 5, 5), 1, "Data row");
            testchart.AddLineGraph(source4, Color.FromRgb(10, 6, 7), 1, "Data row");
            testchart.AddLineGraph(source5, Color.FromRgb(20, 8, 9), 1, "Data row");
            testchart.Viewport.FitToView();
            Thread simThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Simulation));
            simThread.IsBackground = true;
            simThread.Start();
        }

        private void Simulation()
        {
            int i = 0;
            while (true)
            {
                Point p1 = new Point(i * 10, i*10);
                if (i % 2 == 0)//here i tried to break first line in the graph
                {
                    source1.AppendAsync(Dispatcher, p1);
                }
                else
                {
                    Point p5 = new Point(Math.Sign(i*10),i*10);
                    source5.AppendAsync(Dispatcher, p5);
                }

                Point p2 = new Point(i *50, i*10);
                source2.AppendAsync(Dispatcher, p2);
                Point p3 = new Point(i * 1000, i);
                source3.AppendAsync(Dispatcher, p3);
                Point p4 = new Point(i * 1500, i);
                source4.AppendAsync(Dispatcher, p4);
                i++;
                Thread.Sleep(1000);

            }
        }
```

Comment: This is test application.Here i simply add points using method simulation.

Comment: it is a ChartPlotter

Comment: yeah , from Codeplex

Comment: i currently don't have access to codeplex to try... evil proxy settings =P ... but what's the implementation of observabledatasource. is this your doing or some library?

Comment: i take it that this emmits some event with new data and the chart control puts them on the view. so the point where to get this done is there... or you write an adapter suppressing the events that have Y=0

Comment: you might also have to start a new line graph when this happens

Comment: yeah , i am referring lib "DynamicDataDisplay.dll"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is a class emmiting new ObservableDataSources (or adapters that you can stop emmiting new points) whenever the last datapoint has Y of >0. Whenever the Voltage is 0 you need to make the UI stop listening to that datasource. You emmit an event and Add another Linegraph to the chart when the Voltage is >0 and you are there..